# How can I use strncat without buffer overflow concerns?

Tags: c, string, buffer-overflow

I have a buffer, I am doing lot of strncat. I want to make sure I never overflow the buffer size.

```
char buff[64];

strcpy(buff, "String 1");

strncat(buff, "String 2", sizeof(buff));

strncat(buff, "String 3", sizeof(buff));
```

Instead of sizeof(buff), I want to say something buff - xxx. I want to make sure I never override the buffer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take into consideration the size of the existing string and the null terminator

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 64
char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];

//Use strncpy
strncpy(buff, "String 1", BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
buff[BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0';

strncat(buff, "String 2", BUFFER_SIZE - strlen(buff) - 1);

strncat(buff, "String 3", BUFFER_SIZE - strlen(buff) - 1);
```

Comment: buff[BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0'; is not needed as strncat always zero terminates

Comment: @fliX strncpy doesn’t. If count is reached before the entire string src was copied, the resulting character array is not null-terminated. But for this specific example, where BUFFER_SIZE=64 and "String 1" is shorter, you’re right, it’s unneeded because strncpy will also copy the null: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy

Answer (score 15):

Why not use `snprintf`? Unlike `strncat` it expects the size of the buffer, but more importantly, there's no hidden O(n).

Strcat needs to find the null-terminator on each string it concatenates, and each time run through the whole buffer to find the end. Each time the string gets longer, strcat slows down.  Sprintf, on the other hand can keep track of the end. you'll find that

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s%s%s", "String1", "String2", "String3");
```

Is frequently a faster, and more readable soluton.

Comment: That sounds good. However, I have several buffers/strings to be written to one global buffer. That also means to wait until I have all the strings/buffers available in order to use snprintf, else the buffer would be overwritten.

Comment: If you can't wait, `snprintf` returns the number of characters written, so you can store the buffer offset, allowing `offset+=snprintf(buf+offset, (sizeof buf)-offset, "%s", "String2")`

Comment: There is strength in this answer. strcat has an implicit search for the NULL terminator.

Answer (score 7):

The way you use the `strncat` function in your orignal code would actually be appropriate for another function: `strlcat` (note `l` instead of `n`). The `strlcat` function is not standard, yet it is a popular implementation-provided replacement for `strncat`. `strlcat` expects the total size of the entire destination buffer as its last argument.

Meanwhile, `strncat` expects the size of the *remaining* unused portion of the target buffer as its third argument. For this reason, your original code is incorrect.

I would suggest that instead of doing that horrible abuse of `strncpy` and making explicit rescans with those `strlen` calls (both issues present in Joe's answer), you either use an implementation-provided `strlcat` or implement one yourself (if your implementation provides no `strlcat`).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strlcpy

Answer (score 6):

This is the best way to do it.  `sizeof()` just gives you size of the pointer to the data if you don't allocate it locally (you did allocate locally in this case but better to do it this way and it will work if the code is re-factored).

```
#define MAXBUFFSIZE 64

char buff[MAXBUFFSIZE];

buff[0] = 0;  // or some string

strncat(buff, "String x",MAXBUFFSIZE - strlen(buff) - 1);
```

Comment: In that case, `sizeof` will give him the size of the entire buffer since it's an array, not a dynamically allocated block of memory.

Comment: @Hogan: Not true. When `sizeof` is applied to an array object, it evaluates to the total size of the array object. There's no "pointer to the data" of any kind in the OP's code.

Comment: I like that I got down voted and the accepted answer was stolen from mine since it was posted at least a minute after.

Comment: @yan -- true points for a local buffer -- I modified to point out my true point.  If it was re-factored to be allocated there would be ugly bugs.

Comment: @andreyt - see above comment -- I can't notify 2 people it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Hogan has answered the question sufficently; however, if you are worried about buffer overflows in `strcat(...)` you should equally be worried about buffer overflows in all the other string functions.

Use `strnlen(...)` and `strncpy(...)` to really make sure you stay within your buffer.  If you don't have a `strnlen(...)` function, write it.

Comment: Both `strnlen` and `strncpy` are functions that work with fixed-width strings. They have nothing to do with null-terminated strings. Meanwhile, the OP is interested in null-terminated strings specifically, as follows from the question. It is true, that one can often see `strncpy` being *misused* withr null-terminated strings, all right. But what is `strnlen` doing here is totally unclear to me.

Comment: Generally speaking the treatment of null terminated strings as being possibly bound by a fixed length string is what prevents a buffer overflow.  When relying on null termination (by using the non-n function), you rely on the null terminator being only so far from the start of the string, which is a recipe for possibly overflowing the buffer you are copying into (if the assumption about the null terminating character doesn't hold).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `memccpy` instead of `strncat` in this case - it's safer and much faster. (It's also faster than the approach with `snprintf` [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904517/3812944) by Dave):

```c
/**
 * Returns the number of bytes copied (not including terminating '\0').
 * Always terminates @buf with '\0'.
 */ 
int add_strings(char *buf, int len)
{
    char *p = buf;

    if (len <= 0)
        return 0;

    p[len - 1] = '\0'; /* always terminate */

    p = memccpy(buf, "String 1", '\0', len - 1);
    if (p == NULL)
        return len - 1;

    p = memccpy(p - 1, "String 2", '\0', len - 1 - (p - buf));
    if (p == NULL)
        return len - 1;

    p = memccpy(p - 1, "String 3", '\0', len - 1 - (p - buf));

    return (p == NULL ? len : p - buf) - 1;
}
```