# How do the execution speeds of snprintf and strncat compare?

Tags: c, string

I have a program which concatenates some number of strings in a buffer.

I was using strncpy before. After looking into some suggetions on web to use snprintf instead of strncat, I switched to snprintf. However, I have noticed a delay in execution of this part of program(string concatenation) then before. Is this possible, that snprintf can slow down the program exucution speed? If not then I will look for some other factors in my program.

```
if(iOffset<MAX_BUFF_SIZE && iOffset>0)
{
  ....... 
  iOffset += snprintf(cBuff+iOffset, sizeof(cBuff)-iOffset, "%s", "String1");
  ...... 
}
```

I repeat the above code snippet like 12 times in order to append strings to cBuff.

Edit : It repeats 12 times after each 1 sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of suggestions that come to mind:

- don't optimize your program too early
- when you're ready to optimize, use a tool like a profiler to discover where the real slow downs are

If you're not familiar with profiling, or are really eager to know the timing details you can always include timers around your code.  See references on gettimeofday() or clock() and the appropriate caveats about those codes.  Essentially you can get the time before execution, the time after and compare them.  Comment out your line of code and put in the old code and time it.

With all that said ... that's part of what a profiler does for you.  Figuring out "why" something is slow is sometimes complex because there may be other considerations going on (ie at the hardware level) that you're not aware of.

The execution of a function 12 times is probably trivial compared to the total execution time of the program.

Comment: The program was working fine before when I was using strncat.... after I referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903997/usage-of-strncat, I changed my program to use snprintf and hence a reduction in speed... Could be some other reason as well, not sure...

Comment: The answerer in your link mentioned they believed snprintf was faster in a general sense.  Editing to give you another idea.

Comment: The reason for using `snprintf` is not that it's faster, except possibly in cases of very long strings. The reason is that it's a clean and safe string generation idiom for C.

Answer (score 4):

`strncat` suffers from the [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm) problem. The way you're using `snprintf` does not (though it's possible to use `strncat` that way too, and sidestep the problem that way).

Comment: So you mean, there doesnt seems to be any harm in using snprintf compared to strncat?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you take into account the issue that Chris Jester-Young referred to, by accounting for the "[Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)" problem, you are likely to find that in a head to head comparison that `strncat()` is quicker than `snprintf()` - in the way that you are using it.

`snprintf()` does have the (albeit minor, in this case) overhead of having to parse the format string that `strncat()` does not.

The snippet of code that you provided is different enough from the example given in [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903997/usage-of-strncat) to potentially change the comparison.

As Stephen has mentioned, for most platforms running `strncpy()` 12 times versus `snprintf()` should produce a negligible difference. The use of a profiler would be useful here to make sure that you're concentrating on the right area.

---

In the example that you have provided you are trying to append a const string to your buffer. If that is what you're doing in your real code (rather than just as a simple example) and the string copying is *really* a significant area of execution time, you might be able to optimise that area.

One common method of optimisation is to find calculations that can be pre-computed at compile time, rather than at execution time. *If* you are only interested in handling const strings you may be able to effectively precompute the length of the strings and then use `memcpy()`, instead of `strncpy()` to perform the string append. `memcpy()` is typically very well optimised to your platform.

Of course such a solution would be at the expense of having to take more care of buffer overflows and pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the "repeated concatenation" idiom and just using `snprintf` to do it is not genuinely following the suggestion to avoid `strcat`. You should be doing something like:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s%s%s%s", str1, str2, str3, str4);
```

This will be a lot faster than repeated calls to `snprintf`, which would incur a lot of overhead for each call, and it would actually be using the idiom correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a profiler, so I can't say for sure what is slow.

As @chris mentions,  strncat can do more work than it needs to in finding the end of the destination string over and over.   You might have been able to mitigate that since  it appears you are tracking space consumed, so you can start from the end on each subsequent call.

On the other hand,     snprintf  likely has to do extra work compared to a strcat or strcpy, because it must parse the "%s" on each call to figure out how to deal with the variable argument list.

I'm not surprised that strncat could run faster, especially in the absence of aggressive optimization levels.

Answer (score 0):

People who mentioned not to optimize early after you noticed a slow down are  silly.  In this case, you don't even need to run a profiler.  You already have empirical evidence switching to snprintf slowed down your program.

I work in the financial industry where performance is key and almost always prefer sprintf to snprintf.  It is possible to write fast and stable apps with it within a tigthly controlled environment.