# character concatenation in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to do in C, what can be achieved in Java as follows

```
String str = "hello";
System.out.println(str + 'a');
```

I have written the following.
 1. It doesn't work
 2. Is there an easier way to do this in C, something that can be achieved in java in a single line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* charcat(char str[], char c);

int main(void)
{
 char str[] = "hello";
 printf("%s\n",charcat(str,'a'));
}

char* charcat(char str[], char c)
{
 char newstr[] = {c,'\0'};
 char temp[20];

 strcpy(temp,str);
 strcat(temp,newstr);

 return temp;
}
```

EDIT : 
I have edited based on ameyCU's response.

```
char* charcat(char str[], char c);

int main(void)
{
 char str[] = "hello";

 printf("%s\n",charcat(str,'a'));
}

char* charcat(char str[], char c)
{
 char* temp;
 char newstr[] = {c,'\0'};

 temp = malloc((strlen(str) + 1)* sizeof(char));
 strcpy(temp,str);
 return strcat(temp,newstr);
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
char* charcat(char str[], char c);

int main(void)
{
 char str[] = "hello";
 char temp[20];

 strcpy(temp,str);
 printf("%s\n",charcat(temp,'a'));
}

char* charcat(char str[], char c)
{
 char newstr[] = {c,'\0'};
 return strcat(str,newstr);
}
```

Comment: Why thinking in Java mode will hope you in C mode? It is like thinking in English and speaking French, Two different languages

Comment: You cannot return an automatic array, it goes out of scope.

Comment: unfortunately, C has no built-in dynamic string handling, but it's easy to write your own function and use it… if you know C.

Comment: Was exactly this not asked just yesterday?

Comment: @user3121023, I dont' just want to print, I want to save it somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you were trying to do was this:

```
char* charcat(char str[], char c)
{
 char newstr[] = {c,'\0'};
 char *temp=(char *)malloc((strlen(str)+1+1)*sizeof(char));

 strcpy(temp,str);
 strcat(temp,newstr);

 return temp;
}
```

make sure you free() the pointer.

Comment: I find your answer helpful. But I have one question that is not directly related to the original post. I see that you are typecasting temp to char*, so does that convert temp from being type char to being type char*. Is this same as char* temp=malloc((strlen(str)+1+1)*sizeof(char));

Comment: that is perfectly ok. It is unnecessary anyway. a Void pointer(which is returned by calloc and malloc) can be automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type in this case. Please check this link [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you return a local variable.

```
return temp;
```

`temp` is local variable and its scope is just inside the function it is declared.

After concatenation -`strcat(temp,newstr);`

You can do this  -

```
strcpy(str,temp);
return str;
```

But this will also change the contents of original array.

### EDIT

To keep original array intact assign a pointer to string in function and return the pointer .

And also to use functions like `strcpy` and `strcat` you need to include `string.h` header.

Comment: I do not want to do that since I don't want to change the contents of the original string I passed. Is there another way?

Comment: @saltandwater Yes if you want to keep original array to be intact assign a pointer to it inside function.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Please can you have a look at my edit above and see if it's right. Please give me feedback about the malloc line. Is that correct?

Comment: @saltandwater  Yes that's correct `temp = malloc((strlen(str) + 2)* sizeof(char));`  should do it . As you want extra character to be added and `1` for null character. And also you can `return` the pointer instead  i.e  `return temp;` and free it in `main`.

Comment: @saltandwater  This is exactly what Arita Chakraborty answered .Please take a look at her answer.

Comment: thank you. I just have one more question. What I'm doing above, is this same as declaring a temp variable inside main, copying the contents of the original string to temp and calling the function charcat using that temp variable. Something like EDIT 2 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84888/discussion-between-ameycu-and-saltandwater).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strcat()` function

```
char  str1[20]="hello";
strcat(str1,"c");
printf("%s",str1);
```

Comment: @Steephen, this is not what I'm looking for. Note that "c" is not a string. It's a character like char c = 'c'; for me.

Answer (score 1):

This uses `snprintf()` to get the required length for the target string. Memory is allocated and then `snprintf()` creates the target string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char* charcat(char str[], char c);

int main ( ) {
    char str[] = "hello";
    char *output = NULL;

    printf ( "str-> %s\n\n", str);
    if ( ( output = charcat ( str, 'a'))) {//successful return of pointer
        printf ( "output-> %s\n", output);
        free ( output);//release memory
    }
    return 0;
}

char* charcat(char str[], char c)
{
    char *temp = NULL;
    int length = 0;

    length = snprintf ( NULL, 0, "%s%c", str, c);//get required length
    if ( ( temp = malloc ( length + 1))) {//allocate plus one for '\0'
        snprintf ( temp, length + 1, "%s%c", str, c);//malloc succeeds make target
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use **strncat()** instead of strcat to avoid [buffer overflows](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_overflow_attack).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main ()
{
  char str[20] = "hello";
  strncat (str, "a", sizeof(str) - strlen(str) - 1);
  printf("%s",str);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
helloa
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 49ms)
```

Comment: Also refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903997/how-can-i-use-strncat-without-buffer-overflow-concerns]

Comment: Hmmm, This answer recommends " strncat() instead of strcat to avoid buffer overflows" yet then does `sizeof(str) - strlen(str) - 1` which can easily underflow unsigned arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Something like Java in a single line

```
// String str = "hello";
// System.out.println(str + 'a');

const char *str = "hello";
printf("%s%c\n", str, 'a');
```

Or is one wants to print a concatenated string, we need to do memory management.

```
char *charcatconst char *src, int ch) {
  size_t len = strlen(src);
  char *s = memcpy(malloc(len+2), src, len);  // Out-of-memory check omitted.
  s[len] = ch;
  s[len+1] = '\0';
  return s;
} 

// simple usage, but a memory leak
puts(charcat("hello", 'a'));

// Better to free memory explicitly
char *s = charcat("hello", 'a');
puts(s);
free(s);
```