# Efficient way to find and then copy a substring in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, substring

I just want to find a special sub-string in another string and save it as another string. Here is the code:

```
char sub[13]={};
char *ptr = sub;
char src[100] = "SOME DATE HERE CBC: 2345,23, SOME OTHER DATA";
//                              |----------|
ptr = strstr(src,"CBC:");
strncpy(sub,ptr,sizeof(sub)-1);
```

Is this an efficient way or does a better method exist for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Simple and effective, I would say. No need for `ptr` I think?

Comment: empty braces are invalid C initialization. Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: `strncpy()`, despite its name, was not designed to work with strings. In your case, it will not write a `'\0'` to `sub[12]` *(which may already be there)*.

Comment: That should be: `if (ptr = strstr(src,"CBC:")) strncpy(sub,ptr,sizeof(sub)-1);` because the substring could not have been found.

Comment: @pmg, the string was initialized and so will have a zero at its end.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: illegally initialized :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strings in C, how to get subString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114377/strings-in-c-how-to-get-substring)

Comment: Functions from the C standard library are normally optimized, so using `strstr` is probably more efficient than trying to roll your own...

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher without ptr, we can not assign the strstr output.

Comment: With `sub,src` lengths of B and C, a simple solution is `O(B*C)`. An effective  solution is `O(B + C)`.  Choose one.   `strstr()` might be encoded either way.  Recommend  to  just trust the lib.

Comment: "I just want to find a **special** sub-string in another string and **save** it as another string" Is it only me who thinks the task has no sense? Why not just set a flag?

Comment: @Matt `sub[]`and its _special data_ after the matching sub-string, may be needed long after `str[]` is changed.

Comment: @chux But that data is just a constant string. In practice it's almost always easier to operate with flags/indexes into arrays of literals.

Comment: @Matt As a typical [mcve], it is reasonable to assume `char src[]` is not constant but only given the value of `"SOME DATE HERE CBC: 2345,23, SOME OTHER DATA"` to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @Matt The data after CBC: is changing every 1 seconds. It should be extracted and then interpreted in some way.

Comment: @ImanH Still I don't see the need to save the literal prefix "CBC: ". Also the intepretation of a 13-byte string should not be too elaborate, so it could probably be done in-place effectively eliminating any need to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this an efficient way or does a better method exist for this?

**Pros:**

Uses `strstr()` which is likely more efficient and correct that coding your own search.

**Cons:**

Does not handle the case when `strstr()` return `NULL` resulting in *undefined behavior* (UB). [@Paul Ogilvie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736110/efficient-way-to-find-and-then-copy-a-substring-in-c/52743108#comment92397076_52736110)

```
ptr = strstr(src,"CBC:");
// add test
if (ptr) {
  // copy
} else {
  // Handle not found, perhaps `sub[0] = '\0';`
}
```

`char sub[13]={};` is not compliant C code.  [@pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736110/efficient-way-to-find-and-then-copy-a-substring-in-c/52743108#comment92397164_52736110).  A full initialization of the array is not needed - even though it is a common good practice.

Code does not quite fulfill "want to find a special sub-string in another string and save it as another string".  Its more like "want to find a special sub-string in another string and save it *and more* as another string".

`strncpy(sub,ptr,sizeof(sub)-1)` can unnecessarily mostly fill the array with null characters.  This is inefficient when `ptr` points to a string much less than `sizeof(sub)`.  Code could use `strncat()` but that is tricky.  See this good answer [@AnT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904422/2410359).

```
// alternative
char src[100] = "SOME DATE HERE CBC: 2345,23, SOME OTHER DATA";

char sub[13];
sub[0] = '\0';

const char *ptr = strstr(src, "CBC:");
if (ptr) {
  strncat(sub, p, sizeof sub - 1);
}
```

Comment: _strncpy(sub,ptr,sizeof(sub)-1) can unnecessarily mostly fill the array with null characters._ 
The memory for _src_ is allocated so far. Is the inefficiency in its computational complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Unless this piece of code is in a critical path **and** it's the actual source of a performance bottleneck, then just stick to what you have. Default `strstr` implementation should be quite adequate for the task.

You *can* squeeze some peanuts by pre-computing the end of `src`, for example, so you could use `memcmp` (an unconditional loop) instead of `strncpy` (which has a conditional loop) when extracting the `sub`. If you know beforehand the substring you are searching for, you can optimize around that too; especially if it's exactly 4 characters. And so on and so forth.

But if you *are* after these peanuts, you might be (much) better off by redoing the code to not extract `sub` to begin with and use something like ranged strings to keep track of where it is in the source string.