# Warning : call to __builtin___strncat_chk might overflow destination buffer [enabled by default] In function ‘strncat’

Tags: c, buffer, overflow, warnings

I get this warnings while compiling a 'C' language file.

```
In function ‘strncat’,inlined from ‘O281DC3F563F92003x’ at util.c:817:13:
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/bits/string3.h:152:3: warning: call to 
__builtin___strncat_chk might overflow destination buffer [enabled by 
default]

In function ‘strncat’,inlined from ‘UFE191C0002FB606Eb’ at util.c:3231:25:
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/bits/string3.h:152:3: warning: call to 
__builtin___strncat_chk might overflow destination buffer [enabled by 
default]

In function ‘strncat’,
```

How can I remove these warnings?

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You definitely don't want to show 3,000+ lines of code.  Reduce the code down to a bare minimum.  You'll find that something is being copied into a string and the length is specified wrong.  You work out how it should be called.  One wrong way to use `strncpy()` is: `strncpy(target, source, sizeof(source));` — the size should be the size of the target, hence `strncpy(target, source, sizeof(target));`.  Remember, `strncpy()` does not guarantee null termination.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904517/4049851), you can replace easily the usage of `strncat` with `snprintf` which takes in argument the site of the buffer and makes it safe to use.

`strncat` example:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 32
char buf[BUF_SIZE];

strncpy(buf, "foo", sizeof(buf) -1);
strncat(buf, "bar", sizeof(buf) - strlen(buf) -1);
```

Safer `snprintf` example:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 32
char buf[BUF_SIZE];

snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s%s", "foo", "bar");
```

The downside of this method is that you have to use an intermediate buffer if you actually want to concatenate as:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s%s", buf, "bar");
```

results in undefined behavior.